# Restricting The Viewing of Forms Per User

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Please could someone assist with the following:

I'm trying to restrict the viewing of forms using bootstrap and Meteor. In other words, user A logs in and creates a simple (or 2, or 3...) form using a modal which then displays in the html on a panel. How do I ensure that when user B logs in, he only sees his particular forms and not "user A's" forms?

I haven't included any code as I haven't started working on this problem as yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something you need to deal with using your publications/subscriptions. See [here](https://www.meteor.com/try/11) and [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) for learning ressources.

Basically, what should happen is that when user A creates a form (or any object), you store it into a collection along with the user id (`Meteor.userId()`). You subscribe to a publication in your page where you send only the items belonging to the current user Id.

That should solve your problem, and make you ready for all the similar (and common) cases where you need to disclose selected information only, depending on the context or the user. Moreover, it means that your users will be able to find back the items they left in their previous sessions.